# Why "constructor invocation" doesn't fire any compiler (g++) warning?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-warnings

I implemented a shared library which should be thread safe. To protect the critical areas I used `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` from the C++11 standard.

The typo was that I omitted the object itself:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());
```

Instead of

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_obj(getMutexObj());
```

And copy/pasted it in every place... Needless to say that it took me a while to root cause it when multi threaded applications began to crash unpredictably.

Just to cover all the points, the declaration of `getMutexObj()` and the mutex itself are the following:

```
...
mutable std::mutex  m_mutex;
...
std::mutex& getMutexObj() const
{
    return m_mutex;
}
```

All the code was compiled with `g++ 5.2.0` with the following warning flags:

```
WARNINGS := -pedantic \
            -Wall \
            -Wextra \
            -Werror \
            -Wconversion \
            -Woverloaded-virtual \
            -Wcast-qual \
            -Wctor-dtor-privacy \
            -Wdisabled-optimization \
            -Wuninitialized \
            -Wformat=2 \
            -Winit-self \
            -Wlogical-op \
            -Wmissing-declarations \
            -Wmissing-include-dirs \
            -Wold-style-cast \
            -Wredundant-decls \
            -Wshadow \
            -Wsign-conversion \
            -Wsign-promo \
            -Wstrict-null-sentinel \
            -Wstrict-overflow=5 \
            -Wswitch-default \
            -Wundef \
            -Wunused \
            -Wfloat-equal \
            -Wsuggest-final-methods \
            -Wsuggest-final-types \
            -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant
```

**How comes that the compiler didn't fire any warning on `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());`?**

I tried the following code just to see if the compiler throws warnings on them:

```
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());
    int(23);
    23;
    uint16_t remove_me = 23;
```

and for line 2,3 and 4 I got warnings BUT not for line 1... WHY?

```
<.../path/...>:32:16: error: statement has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
         int(23);
                ^
<.../path/...>:33:11: error: statement has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
         23;
           ^
<.../path/...>:34:18: error: unused variable 'remove_me' [-Werror=unused-variable]
         uint16_t remove_me = 23;
                  ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

**EDIT1**

I noticed that the question is a little confusing since almost all of the answers are related to

> for line 2,3 and 4 I got warnings BUT not for line 1... WHY?

However the real question here is:

**How comes that the compiler didn't fire any warning on `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());`?**

Is there any switch at all to make the compiler warn about such code???

**EDIT2**

As *cpplearner* mentioned in his comment, `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());` is seen as a function declaration of function named `getMutexObj` which returns `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.

I looked at the disassembly and saw that in case of `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());`, there are no related opcodes at all.

However when I changed it to

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{getMutexObj()};
```

and looked at the disassembly, it was compiled as temporal object creation but again without any warning.

Comment: What warning would you expect? You're legally calling the constructor of the class without assigning the result to any variable. The constructor could (and does) have side effects so "statement has no effect" warning would be wrong.

Comment: @TomaszSodzawiczny "calling the constructor" explicitly is not recommended (if not allowed due to undefined behavior) as long as I know. So yes, I would expect some warning in that case.

Comment: @AlexLop. I'm not sure what you mean. You can't call a constructor explicitly.

Comment: @TartanLlama That's my point: std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj()); looks like "call a constructor explicitly"

Comment: I believe that the functional notation of type conversion covers that (see 12.1.2 and  5.2.3. of C++ Standard) and basically acts like creating an unnamed temporary object and then dropping it. 
It is a legal operation, and could be used willingly in some scenarios I guess.

Comment: @TomaszSodzawiczny I understand that it is legal... `int(23);` is also legal but there is a warning to catch such thing. There are also warnings to catch assignments from signed to unsigned types which might be done in purpose. *"creating an unnamed temporary object and then dropping it. It is a legal operation"* but again I would expect to have an option to make the compiler to warn on such thing. And if it is done in purpose one can disable such warning.

Comment: I think `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());` is a declaration of a function whose name is `getMutexObj` and whose return type is `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @cpplearner I would be correct in this case: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> getMutexObj();` the one in my code doesn't seem to be the proper function declaration...

Comment: @AlexLop. You can add a pair of parentheses around a declarator without altering its meaning, that is, `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (getMutexObj());` has the same meaning as `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> getMutexObj();`.

Comment: @cpplearner You are right. I checked it and it is indeed seen as a function declaration however even if I fix it by `{}`, it will create and destroy a temporal object but still without any warning... I'll update the question with your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());
```

This should actually give an error, because it declares a function called `getMutexObj` but that is already declared with a different return type (and you can't overload on return type). This is a GCC bug, I've reported it as [bug 69855](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69855).

This case is different:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{getMutexObj()};
```

This *does* create a temporary, but there's no warning here because compilers aren't magic.

Warnings are added to compilers to catch common mistakes, but someone has to actually implement the code to check for it, and issue a warning. That doesn't just happen by magic or by fairies coming and improving the compiler at night when nobody is looking.

In this case the compiler sees that you are creating a temporary variable, which has side effects (it writes to a global memory location, the mutex, and issues memory barriers). The compiler doesn't know that those side effects are not exactly what you wanted to do, because it's not magic.

It would be nice if the compiler did warn here, and someone did write a patch for GCC to warn about this, see [bug 36587](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36587), but as I pointed out in that bug report, it would also warn about valid code. It would be bad if the compiler issued a warning every time you create a temporary variable with side effects. This is a valid scenario using similar syntax:

```
std::ofstream( "./lockfile" );
```

This opens an `ofstream` with a particular name, which will create the file if it doesn't exist already. The compiler should not warn about this, because it's perfectly valid.

So to warn for your example, but not other similar pieces of code, would require some additional information to tell the compiler that the `lock_guard` type should never be used this way. That means annotating the `lock_guard` somehow and teaching the compiler to recognise that annotation. Again, fairies are not going to come and do that work, so it hasn't happened because it hasn't been prioritised and nobody has written a patch.

GCC supports a `warn_unused` attribute on constructors, see [bug 55203](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55203), but that wouldn't help for `lock_guard` because the correct use of the class means it is always "unused" (you never refer to it after construction). A different attribute and warning would need to be implemented for this case.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be satisfying for me. I just had an impression that things like `className{someVar}` are not commonly used and there probably should be an option to make the compiler warn about it. But according to your answer looks like my assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike `23;` with the message *"error: statement has no effect"*, creating an unnamed temporary `lock_guard` *does* have the effect of locking and unlocking the mutex.

This has the side effect of a memory barrier that is visible to other threads.

Comment: I agree that it has a side effect. But calling a constructor explicitly is not recommended (if I am not mistaking) so I would expect to see some warning here...

Comment: @alex who doesn't recommend it?  As an example of where it might be used, if you have an atomic variable guarded by a mutex and condition variable, you might want to set the atomic variable, toggle the mutex on and off, then fire the condition variable.  I mean, I could see adding this warning, but it is very different than the int case, and you did ask about "why would it not have a warning, while the int case does".  This answers exactly that question.  None of the warnings you posted apply here, which is why they did not fire.

Comment: @Yakk I should have probably make my question clearer. The real question is **How comes that the compiler didn't fire any warning on std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());?**

Comment: @Alex - Consider the code you intended to write `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_obj(getMutexObj());`. Why doesn't the compiler issue an unused variable warning for that? `lock_obj` isn't used anywhere else in the function. Because the construction and destruction of the object is useful. And it might be even without having a name.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks Bo. Do you know if there is an option to make the compiler warn about such code?

Comment: @BoPersson BTW, can you give an example where construction and destruction of the object at "the same point" may be useful? In case of the `lock_obj` object the construction and the destruction are useful because they happen at the different points... And of course +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Alex Indeed  the `lock_guard` case isn't a good example when anonymous construction can be useful, and obviously your problem was that it caused behaviour unwanted here. However I rather often use constructs of the patter `ClassA(initParameters).doSomething(methodParameters)`, when there's no need to keep the object alive any longer. And I can image cases where the `doSomething()` part is already executed in the constructor. My point being, it's impossible for the compiler to judge what you're up to in this case, and I can't see a bad practice here that the coder should be warned about.

Comment: @Murphy I doubt about `ClassA(initParameters).doSomething(methodParameters)` being a good coding practice. If you want to call `doSomething()` why to overkill it with construction and destruction of a temporal object each time? Why not creating a global (singleton) "service" object to supply methods like `doSomething()`? Anyway, there are many things in C++ which could be done on purpose but still compiler warns about them. I am curious why creation of an "anonymous" object is not covered by any warning...

Comment: @Alex Because, first, the constructor does some general initialization, and, second, the class is also instantiated as a stack object in other places, using `doSomething()` and other methods, which may contain quite complex tasks and make use of member variables, too. The construct above is just a shortcut when all you need is one call to a local object. `static` or singleton is not always the answer...

Comment: @AlexLop. my answer gives an example where constructing a temporary with side effects is useful: `std::ofstream( "./lockfile" );`

Comment: Another thought: Every use of a default parameter creates an anonymous, temporary object {`int doThat(const std::string& str = std::string())`}, as well as container initialization without initializer list {`const QList<int> listOfInts(QList<int>() << 14 << 32 << 42)`}. And I assume this is perfectly good coding practice.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is - the compiler didn't fire any warnings because this is a valid expression which could (theoretically) be used on purpose. The expression:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(getMutexObj());
```

is a functional notation of type conversion, defined in the Standard:

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)**
>
> 1) A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the
>   specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a
>   single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in
>   definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4). *(...)*

and is interpreted as static cast (5.2.9.4):

> An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a
>   static_cast of the form static_cast(e) if the declaration `T t(e);`
>   is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The
>   effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the
>   declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable
>   as the result of the conversion. *(...)*

---

The compiler could not give any of the warnings it does for

```
int(23);
uint16_t remove_me = 23;
```

Because you are not creating a variable (which could be unused) and the expression *does* have an effect - which is calling the constructor of `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.

Comment: I understand that it is legal... int(23); is also legal but there is a warning to catch such thing. There are also warnings to catch assignments from signed to unsigned types which might be done in purpose. "creating an unnamed temporary object and then dropping it. It is a legal operation" but again I would expect to have an option to make the compiler to warn on such thing. And if it is done in purpose one can disable such warning.

Comment: I do agree that in this case it would be useful - it is a bug tricky to catch. ;) I just answered why this 2 warnings don't apply, also I cannot think of any other that could.

Answer (score 3):

The guard is an aggregate data type (in contrast to the primitive types you're comparing it with) where the constructor can contain custom code; so "statement has no effect" is (or may be) not correct - it may well be your intention to just construct and immediately destroy an object. "unused variable" doesn't match either, as the temporary object has no name and is not persistent until the end of the block.

Comment: I agree that it has a side effect. But I would expect to see some warning here since calling the constructor is a bad coding practice (as long as I know).

Comment: I just tried here with a class I had at hand, GCC warnings `-Wall -Wextra` enabled. No warning, it just passes.

Comment: @AlexLop. you're not "calling the constructor" you're creating a temporary variable, and that is not bad practice, it has valid uses, e.g. see my example at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36587#c5

Answer (score 2):

I believe is about the compiler not knowing the exact context of a referenced variable. The cases that raise a warning are not referenced values, they are primitive types. The compiler is not aware of what you are trying to accomplish, because it doesn't know what the library does.

Also, in this case, you are effectively locking the variable. But it could be something else. Like starting something outside your program. You don't really need a name if you are not going to stop that something you started.